# How to resize NSTextField when content increase in NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview

i have NSTextField but content that i have to show is not fixed , it will grow dynamically.
is there any way in simple way through which we can change size dynamically.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: This question is already asked many times...so before posting- first do some search and research.

Comment: yes anoop, so many solutions are there, but all doing through code. In my question i have asked is there any setting in interface builder instead of calculating & setting through code.

Comment: You have not mentioned IB anywhere in question !!!  In IB its not there.

Comment: And I asked you to do search and research because your points may be cut-down if someone votes you down.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya it's been asked many times before because it's extremely difficult and nobody (as far as I can find) has ever provided an answer. I've been a cocoa developer for 15 years and after 3 hours trying to get this to work I've given up and will use NSTextView instead of NSTextField – which appears to be buggy when resized while editing

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: I mentioned it is not possible to do with Interface builder, however you can achieve this with Code....in 2012. Now we have Autolayouts and we can use it feature to increasing the sizes automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text field's delegate needs to update the size as the text changes.

The trick is you have to manually update the `stringValue` property, to avoid bugs:

```
override func controlTextDidChange(obj: NSNotification) {
  guard let field = obj.object as? NSTextField else {
    return
  }

  // re-apply the string value, this is necessary for the text field to correctly calculate it's width
  field.stringValue = field.stringValue

  // calculate the new dimensions
  let maxWidth: CGFloat = 500
  let maxHeight: CGFloat = 50
  let size = renameField.sizeThatFits(NSSize(width: maxWidth, height: maxHeight))

  // apply them
  field.frame = NSRect(x: field.frame.origin.x, y: field.frame.origin.y, width: size.width, height: size.height)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to set through Interface Builder.

However you can do through codes:
You can set a delegate on the NSTextField which implements

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
```

Every time the delegate gets called resize the control per your idea above.

Also, this one.

There is a great category on NSString/NSAttributedString by Jerry Krinock which allows you to calculate the height of text based on its width and vice versa:

http://www.sheepsystems.com/sourceCode/sourceStringGeometrics.html

**Edit March 2016** :

Now as Autolayout feature is there for Mac OS applications that helps to increase and decrease the size of textfield and even NSWindow, so you can use them it very easy to use. Just put constraints from either side of the Window, and set the constraints something as ( >= desiredMinimumSize ) and you are done!

Comment: Resizing a text field while it's being edited doesn't work properly, it seems to put the field in a corrupt state where it can no-longer draw itself properly. Making the text field smaller almost works, but increasing the size breaks it completely.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: Now even with IB you can achieve this with Autolayout. I updated the answer.

Comment: Have you tried it? I wasn't able to get it to work with a test project. Are you sure you understand the question? The idea is to increase the width of a field live to fit whatever the user has typed in.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just showing content, as opposed to typing in the text field, then you should use a label, which can be set in IB to "Size To Fit Content". This will cause the label to be just big enough for the content.